# Fill data using a button or link

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a bean action that will set values based on a given field data

```
public void fillSample(final String sin) {
    setParticipantSinInput(sin);
    participant.setEmail(sin + "@example.com");
    participant.setName("Archie " + sin);
    setGenderAtBirthInput(Gender.MALE);
}
```

I want to trigger it using a button/link on the page but I don't want it to validate the input.  At the moment I am getting the following in the logs

```
[WARNING ] There are some unhandled FacesMessages, this means not every FacesMessage had a chance to be rendered.
These unhandled FacesMessages are: 
- Social Insurance Number: Validation Error: Value is required.
- Name: Validation Error: Value is required.
- Gender at birth: Validation Error: Value is required.
- E-mail: Validation Error: Value is required.
```

Or nothing appears on the logs but the data fields do not get populated.  Or the validation appears.

I've tried the following so far

```
<p:commandLink value="fill" action="#{participantBean.fillSample(participantBean.generatedSin)}" 
update="@form"/>

<p:commandLink value="fill" action="#{participantBean.fillSample(participantBean.generatedSin)}" 
immediate="true" update="@form"/>

<p:commandLink value="fill" action="#{participantBean.fillSample(participantBean.generatedSin)}" 
immediate="true" update="@all"/>

<p:commandButton value="fill" action="#{participantBean.fillSample(participantBean.generatedSin)}" 
immediate="true" update="@form"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This combination worked

```
<p:commandLink value="fill" 
  action="#{participantBean.fillSample(participantBean.generatedSin)}"
  update="@form" process="@this">
  <p:resetInput target="@form" />
</p:commandLink>
```

So it will update the current form and only process `@this` which I guess is the button so it does not execute the validations on the whole form.

In addition the `resetInput` is needed in case the form was in an invalid state to begin with.